# Segmented home LAN

Tags: networking, router, lan, switch, wireless-bridge

I'm currently re-organising my home network.

Current setup is pretty much

```
Evil Internet <--> Modem <--> WiFi-Router <--WiFi--> Printer, Laptops etc.
```

There's other devices on the LAN ports of the router, but I'm not drawing them here.

Where I want to go:

```
Evil Internet <--> Modem <--> WiFi-Router <--WiFi--> Printer, Laptops etc.
                                             |
                                             +-----> WiFi-Bridge <--Ethernet--> Router (*) <--Ethernet--> Many wired devices
```

My questions are:

1.) Is a router in the second line (*) the device of choice, or can it be a switch? I could use the LAN ports of the WiFi-Bridge, but I want to have an additional device in between to apply filtering rules on the devices behind the WiFi-Bridge.

2.) Will that router (*), or switch if it is going to be a switch, automatically segment the network in the network layer? If not, what else do I need to do to achieve this?

Thanks.

Edit: Filtering is mostly outbound (ad-blocking etc.) on application layer (DNS, URL black listing etc.). Inbound, ideally, nothing should get through unless the connections are instigated from within the LAN itself. Whether it's a home or enterprise grade router, it's most likely going to be a stand-alone Linux box with a bunch of Ethernet cards.

Comment: please expound on the kind of filtering rules you would like to apply to the wired clients. in particular which direction are you trying to restrict? Additionally are you talking home or enterprise grade router?

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of switch or router depends on whether you want one IP network or two. There are merits and flaws to both. Based on your description, a Router is appropriate, because you want advanced features not available on consumer-grade switches.

The installation of a router will introduce a second IP network, upon which your wired devices will sit. you will have to decide what IP range you want it to use for its LAN, and set your wired clients to use IPs within that range (or enable the routers DHCP feature, and configure an address pool).

If you are using a PC router, you should be able to configure it as you need, but Many people (including myself) have been quite annoyed, that Home grade routers pretty much never let you turn off the firewall completely, so unless you are working with enterprise grade hardware you will experience issues establishing full bi-directional reach-ability between the two networks. In particular, devices on the wifi would not be able to access services on the wired network. Or maybe that's what you want.

The installation of a switch will extend the existing IP network so you would have one larger network, but you do lose the ability to treat that part of your network as "different" from the rest. Personally, This is what I do.

Comment: Awesome answer. Yes, a second network is what I want. In regards reachability: That's also exactly what I want: Two separate networks, both agnostic to each other. The wired network's going to have static IP addresses as well. Sick of DHCP, some devices choke on a server having changed IP address. The only common thing they'll have is upstream Internet access. So a router it is. Thanks!